# Make file macro

Tags: makefile, macros, g++

```
# this is a comment
OBJS = student.o teacher.o class.o
CC = g++
DEBUG = -g
CFLAGS = -Wall –c $(DEBUG)
LFLAGS = -Wall $(DEBUG)

myproj.exe : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJS) –o myproj.exe
student.o : student.h student.cpp
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) student.cpp
teacher.o : teacher.h teacher.cpp
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) teacher.cpp
class.o : class.h student.h teacher.h class.cpp
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) class.cpp
```

can someonte tell me why does CFLAGS and LFALGS have the $(DEBUG) behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you don't have to write it every time you compile or link.

Lets take these two lines from your file:

```
student.o : student.h student.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) student.cpp
```

If you didn't have `$(DEBUG)` in `$(CFLAGS)` you would have to write

```
student.o : student.h student.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUG) student.cpp
```

And do it for *every* rule and command where you want to use `$(DEBUG)`.

Comment: @RaphaelSeize Read [the GCC online manual about command line options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/index.html#toc_Invoking-GCC).